# The live server extension of VS code suddenly stopped working as expected

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, deployment, liveserver

I've been using live server to display the changes to my html/css/JS files. It was working fine until today. Now when I start the live server, and make any changes to my files and save them, the page no longer auto updates and I have to manually refresh the page to be able to see the changes, which is really frustrating.

Things I've tried:

1. Everything on this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70249584/live-server-not-refreshing-browser)
2. A different extension with a similar purpose. (same problem)
3. Set chrome as my default browser in both local system and vs code extension settings.

P.S. The weird thing is, live server doesn't work on chrome, but when I set the browser as microsoft-edge in the extension settings, live server worked perfectly fine, auto updating the page as expected. Is this a chrome only issue?

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there hasn't been a [new release](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/releases) of the extension since august 2020, so this isn't some new bug. Please provide a [mre] / _exact_ steps to reproduce the problem